# I'm Having A Problem With my SVG Font Design

Tags: inkscape, fonts, text, typography, svg

This is my **first take** on making **fonts**. So, please try to be as **elaborate** as possible.

So, i'm going to try and explain my issue as **clean and elaborate** as possible.

I'm using **Inkscape** to create my font. I designed the first letter **"A" using Bezier Curves**. I **stroked** them with the **black color** and **disabled the fill**. I opened the **Glyph Viewer** and added the curves to the reference "A". When I **preview** the letter in the **preview box**, it appears to be **filled** with the **black color**. The point is that I want the letter to **look just the way I designed it**. Here, in my case I **only want the strokes/outlines** to show up in the preview, which will eventually become a **complete** font family.

FYI I have a **backup** for the letter that I created. I designed **each part** of the letter separately and finally **joined** them.

Any remedy for this problem would be deeply **appreciated**!

I'm attaching a **sequence of images** for your reference.

[image: Workspace]

[image: "A" Design]

[image: Font Editor]

[image: Preview]

[image: "A" with Nodes]

Comment: Are you aware that *path winding order* is A Thing for fonts?

Comment: Actually, I really don't know that until you told me! I will keep that in mind too, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glyphs are filled areas with no stroke. Font rendering software is interested only in the edge curves and it fills the interiors, your black stroke is not taken into the account.

Apply Path > Stroke to Path to your shape and make an union of the parts of a glyph before defining it belongs to a font. Then it will appear as originally drawn. Stroke to Path converts the stroke to closed fillable area.

Unfortunately I don't know how to make Inkscape's font editor to display glyphs without a fill. If I break a closed path at some node it's still treated as closed path in font editor's rendering. Hopefully someone who has underhood knowledge writes a proper answer which solves your problem without converting the strokes to paths.

If you use your font in a drawing you can remove the fill color and define a stroke. The problem occurs in the font editor.

BTW many questions has been written how to get single stroke fonts which could be  open curves if needed. SVG font format should support them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try your advice and let you know if that worked!

Comment: Hello there buddy, your advice worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for taking you time answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

After following @user287001's advice it turned out like this...
[image: worked out answer]